# Dataweave to select exact tag from XML Mulesoft

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft

What would be the correct Dataweave expression to get "0011x000014VegoAAC" from XML below?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<order order-no="00000907" xmlns="http://www.demandware.com/xml/impex/order/2006-10-31">
    <order-date>2020-07-10T08:57:05.076Z</order-date>
    <current-order-no>00000907</current-order-no>
    <product-lineitems>
        <product-lineitem>
            <net-price>54.17</net-price>
        </product-lineitem>
    </product-lineitems>
    <custom-attributes>
        <custom-attribute attribute-id="Adyen_pspReference">852594371442812G</custom-attribute>
        <custom-attribute attribute-id="Adyen_value">7099</custom-attribute>
        <custom-attribute attribute-id="sscAccountid">0011x000014VegoAAC</custom-attribute>
    </custom-attributes>
</order>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom-attribute looks like standard tag. Wrap it to the quotes and it will work fine. custom-attribute is an array which is indicated by asterisk in the DW transformation. From this array (line 19 creates it) we filter all items with attribute (indicated by @ character) equal sscAccountId.

Result is array with one element.

```
%dw 2.0
var payload =read('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<order order-no="00000907" xmlns="http://www.demandware.com/xml/impex/order/2006-10-31">
    <order-date>2020-07-10T08:57:05.076Z</order-date>
    <current-order-no>00000907</current-order-no>
    <product-lineitems>
        <product-lineitem>
            <net-price>54.17</net-price>
        </product-lineitem>
    </product-lineitems>
    <custom-attributes>
        <custom-attribute attribute-id="Adyen_pspReference">852594371442812G</custom-attribute>
        <custom-attribute attribute-id="Adyen_value">7099</custom-attribute>
        <custom-attribute attribute-id="sscAccountid">0011x000014VegoAAC</custom-attribute>
    </custom-attributes>
</order>','application/xml')
output application/json
---
(payload.order."custom-attributes".*"custom-attribute") 
 filter (item) -> (item.@"attribute-id" ~= "sscAccountid")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank @Alex, apprently I am one step close your answer but am getting error:Invalid status code: 400, response body: [{"message":"Cannot deserialize instance of reference from START_ARRAY value [line:1, column:423]","errorCode":"JSON_PARSER_ERROR"}] must be something stupid, my code: %dw 2.0
output application/java
ns ns0 http://www.demandware.com/xml/impex/order/2006-10-31
---
[{ 

 PBSI__Customer__c: (payload.ns0#order.ns0#"custom-attributes".*ns0#"custom-attribute")
  filter (item) -> (item.@"attribute-id" == "sscAccountid")
}]

Comment: That is not a DataWeave error. That is probably some other issue. You should open a new question for it.

Comment: @Alex - How can I remove those square bracts from response I want 0011x000014VegoAAC instead of [0011x000014VegoAAC]

Comment: This is array. If you want only first item - use index 0. Like ((payload.order."custom-attributes".*"custom-attribute") 
 filter (item) -> (item.@"attribute-id" ~= "sscAccountid"))[0]